# What's the difference between 'LoadStringA' and 'LoadStringW'?

Tags: winapi

I recently started to learn the Win32 API and I don't understand the main difference between the functions **LoadStringA** and **LoadStringW**.

The only difference that I see are the type of the Parameters, like **LPWSTR** instead of **LPSTR**. When should I use LoadStringA instead of LoadStringW ?

Comment: [Conventions for Function Prototypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/conventions-for-function-prototypes) explains the details behind generic-text mappings in the Windows API. Since string resources are always stored as Unicode strings you should generally call `LoadStringW`, unless you have a *specific* reason to call the ANSI version. If you don't know what reason that might be, use `LoadStringW`.

Comment: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained here in official documentation: [Working with Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings)

> When Microsoft introduced Unicode support to Windows, it eased the
> transition by providing two parallel sets of APIs, one for ANSI
> strings and the other for Unicode strings. For example, there are two
> functions to set the text of a window's title bar:
>
> **SetWindowTextA** takes an ANSI string.
>
> **SetWindowTextW** takes a Unicode
> string.

As for recommendation, where "New" means newer than 1995 or so ...

> **New applications should always call the Unicode versions**. Many world
> languages require Unicode. If you use ANSI strings, it will be
> impossible to localize your application. The ANSI versions are also
> less efficient, because the operating system must convert the ANSI
> strings to Unicode at run time.